# Nesting properties within a link/div

Tags: html, css

So I have this code

```
#Ford a:link{ text-decoration: none; }
```

and this one

```
#Ford {
width:34%;
text-align:center;
border-width:15px;
border-style:inset;
border-color:#F7DC6F;
background-color:teal;
padding:10px 220px;
}
```

is there anyway to put the

> a:link{ text-decoration: none; }

within the other #Ford propierties on CSS?.

Something like

```
#Ford {
width:34%;
text-align:center;
border-width:15px;
border-style:inset;
border-color:#F7DC6F;
background-color:teal;
padding:10px 220px;
 a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
 }
}
```

I've looked up some docs, blogs, etc, and I think it's neither possible nor legal.

Comment: Look into less and sass.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by putting a:link inside #Ford? Do you want the rule to be applied to direct children or all descendants? or some other behavior?

Comment: I just wanted to sum up everything and make it less _italic_ Spaghetti_-ish But yeah, i think the only possible way its to use less/sass/etc but in the end, it just always like that so...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the property a: link only for #Ford you should use this syntax:

```
#Ford > a: link { text-decoration: none}
```

Here's an explanation of what > does:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

Comment: Yeah I know, but my point here its really to just sum up, summarize everything into just one #Ford tag not having the need to duplicate them just for those small propiertes...